Native JavaScript: Intercept and modify all link opening events
Problem Description
There is a time-consuming async function f that takes a URL string and returns the modified one. For example:
async function f(url) { // A dummy time-consuming function
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(url + "#processed");
        }, 1000)
    });
}

I would like all links opened from a certain page to be processed by f before actually opening. Note that I have no control over the actual webpage, only the ability to inject scripts via Tampermonkey. Also, the contents of the webpage can be generated dynamically.
What I've tried
Handling links opened with window.open is rather easy (simply hook the method), but I encountered some problems handling <a> elements. My thought is to add an capture: true listener on document, pause the event and modify the href attribute of <a> when it detects interaction with <a> elements, and then resume the event. This is what I came up with:
const tag1 = "url-handling"; // The element is being handled
const tag2 = "url-handled"; // The element has been handled
const eventName = "url-handle-done"; // The event name signaling completion of handling
function cloneAndStop(e) { // Clone an event and stop the original
    const newEvt = new e.constructor(e.type, e);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return newEvt;
}
async function eventHandler(e) { // Intercept mouse events
    const ele = e.target.tagName === "A" ? e.target : e.target.closest("a");
    if (ele && !ele.hasAttribute(tag2) && ele.href) {
        if (!ele.hasAttribute(tag1)) { // The element is not being handled
            ele.toggleAttribute(tag1, true); // Mark the element as being handled
            const href = ele.href;
            if (!href.startsWith("https://") && !href.startsWith("http://")) return; // Ignore non-HTTP(S) URLs
            const newEvt = cloneAndStop(e);
            console.log(`Intercepted: "${ele.href}"`);
            const url = ele.href;
            const processed = await f(url);
            ele.href = processed; // Modify the URL
            console.log(`Processed: "${ele.href}"`);
            ele.toggleAttribute(tag2, true); // Mark the element as handled
            ele.removeAttribute(tag1); // Remove the being-handled mark
            ele.dispatchEvent(newEvt); // "Resume" the initial event
            ele.dispatchEvent(new Event(eventName, { bubbles: false, cancelable: true })); // Notify other potential handlers
        } else { // The element is being handled by another handler
            const newEvt = cloneAndStop(e);
            console.log(`Waiting: "${ele.href}"`);
            ele.addEventListener(eventName, function () {
                console.log(`Waited: "${ele.href}"`);
                ele.dispatchEvent(newEvt);
            }, { once: true });
        }
    }
}

["click", "mousedown", "auxclick", "contextmenu"].forEach((name) => {
    document.addEventListener(name, eventHandler, { capture: true });
});

It works fine for clicking <a> elements, even with modifier keys, where the processed URL opens after 1 second. But it does not work for auxclick and contextmenu, where I simply receive the following log, but no opening in new tab and showing up context menu:
Intercepted: "https://example.org/"
Waiting: "https://example.org/"
Processed: "https://example.org/#processed"
Waited: "https://example.org/#processed"

By calling window.open for auxclick events, I can somewhat simulate the browser's default action of opening the link on a new page, but I assume there's a way to simulate mouse/pointer events instead of calling window.open.
Related Questions

Use JavaScript to intercept all document link clicks
Intercept all current and future links



To show the context menu you'd need an external app that sends a native key event, it can't be faked from within a userscript. 2) Judging by the log the code is stuck on await f.



If simulating contextmenu is impossible in js, then I might as well give up 2) The log shows Processed: "https://example.org/#processed", so await f is not blocking the code from my point of view.


Ah, the output from two runs is interspersed, I see. Well then auxclick not being dispatched is either a bug or an intentional limitation for whatever reason.
